# Will portable Ubuntu work if PC stuck on Win10 update?

Tags: ubuntu, updates, livecd

Two of my friends have had problems with the recent Win10 feature update resulting in having to re-install Win10 and losing all files.  It gets stuck in a loop from the 'Choose Keyboard' option during out of the box experience.

If I have a live CD of Ubuntu, will I be able to boot the PC from it and backup my files before reinstalling Windows?

Comment: I submitted an edit to the question, see if that fits what you are asking-- that's the question I got based off of the information given.

Comment: Yes, you will..

Comment: It would be better and much easier to do the backups before starting the update. And have a Windows installer USB prepared in advance, just in case.

Comment: If you can boot to a disk or USB and load a different OS then yes of course that will work with Ubuntu from a Live CD as long as your machine has applicable settings set to allow as such and capable of booting from CD-ROM media. This is basic and standard computer functionality so yes that is possible. Are you having trouble with that or something?

Comment: Of course I would back-up my data before installing any update BUT I just have Win10 Home which doesn't allow you to choose whether or not to update,or so I understand. I went through the laborious download of Win Installer to re-install Windows and sorted it out for them but they had some data that had not been recently backed up. I have used portable Ubuntu before on a previous laptop when one Windows failed to recognise one of the two drives and managed to get data back before installing a new drive. I wanted to know ( if it happens again) whether Ubuntu could be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an Ubuntu live DVD/USB to make backup copies of your files which are stored on a non-working Windows operating system. The Ubuntu live session will automatically mount the Windows NTFS partition, and you can easily transfer files from there to another storage device such as a USB external hard drive. You can also install software in a Ubuntu live USB session to make the file transfer easier to do.

I recommend installing Unison file synchronization tool from the default Ubuntu repositories. Unison is a GUI file synchronization tool for Unix and Windows. It allows two replicas of a collection of files and directories to be stored on different hosts (or different disks on the same host), modified separately, and then brought up to date by propagating the changes in each replica to the other.